# Run Console application using Windows Scheduler

Tags: .net, windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have created a console application which run selenium test and open up browser, when running the application exe file it works fine both in Debug & Release mode.

When I try to schedule this console application using Windows Scheduler it starts open up command window but does not open browser.

I am using Window Server 2008 to test this application.

Do I need to add some special permissions to run it as task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the scheduled task with a specific account (ie, your account)? LocalSystem is quite different than a "regular" user account.